# why we need Convert.Int() and Int.Parse() in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

Where we need to use **Convert.Int()** and **Int.Parse()**.
So what is the difference between **Convert.Int()**, **Int.Parse()** and **Int.TryParse**.I know that **Int.TryParse** returns us true/false and perfomance of **Int.TryParse** better than other methods.

1.Why we need **Convert.Int()** and **Int.Parse()**.
2.Actually we can use **Int.TryParse** in everywhere .

Answer (score 1):

It is Convert.ToInt32

`Int.Parse()`
It's used to convert the input into integer. The input integer should be a string which contains only numbers. **it throw error if string is  null.**

`Convert.ToInt32`

It's used to convert the input into integer and bool. The input integer should be an integer; if it's null it will return 0; if it's string, it should only contain the number. **It's handling null value and returning 0**.

`converting the String (which contains long value) to integer.`

**Convert.ToInt32 and Int.Prase** throw exception but Int.TryParse don't throw exception

Uses

`Convert.ToInt32 :- when need to null automatically`

`Int.TryParse:- when string contain long number and use if condition`

Otherwise use int.Pase

[Click Here For More Details](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uses-of-int-parse-convert-toint-and-int-tryparse/#:%7E:text=It%27s%20used%20to%20convert%20the%20input%20into%20integer%20and%20bool,should%20only%20contain%20the%20number.)

Answer (score 0):

That could be true, but ConvertTo.Int could be an old version left there same as int.Parse but int.TryPasre is just synthetic sugar which means it is better in style and error handling